# Forming a local martingale with continuous increasing process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

If $M_t$ is continuous martingale, we know that there exists quadratic variation process which is continuous and increasing. I am interested to know if the converse is also true. To make it precise

> Let $ \{A_t, \mathcal{F_t}; 0\leq t < \infty\}$ be continuous, increasing process starting at 0 a.s. Let $\{B_t, \mathcal{F_t}; 0\leq t < \infty\}$ be standard Brownian motion. Is it true that $M_t := B_{A_t}$ is a local martingale with quadratic variation $A_t$?

I was trying to use time change for Brownian motion. However I am not successful in getting the right formulation with stopping times.

Comment: @ chandu1729 : If $A_t$ is the quadratic variation of a local martingale $M_t$ it is true that $B_{A_t}$ is a local martingale (beware of the filtration though) as it is equal to $M_t$ (that's a theorem that can be found in Karatzas and Shreve's book). In the opposite direction, given any $A_t$ to know if it is the quadratic variation of a local martingale is a question that I can't answer. Note that if $A_t=\int_0^ta(t)dt$ with $a(t)$ having a square root then it is true otherwise ... Best regards